# Getting counts without loading from S3 to DB

Tags: hive, analytics, aggregation, data-warehouse

When the online application makes a request based on the query parameters I have to return the count. To achieve this, we have pipelines which will load a massive amount of data into DB and then when the request is received we query the DB and return the counts.

As the data is present on S3, is there a way to query data directly on S3 when we receive the request and return counts instead of writing the whole infrastructure?

Can I use Hive for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Amazon Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/): it provides a simple way to query data directly on S3.
You just point your data in S3, define the schema required and with a standard SQL [you are good to go](https://medium.com/edureka/amazon-athena-tutorial-c7583053495f).

Comment: but can I make this query when a user makes a request from webapp?

Comment: Sure, you can connect to it [using JDBC Driver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html)